# How to post images to Instagram?

Tags: api, instagram

I'm working on a webshop. And would like to add the feature to be able to post product images to the shops Instagram account when a new product is added.

The thing is that the Instagram API does not seems to allow to post images. Either does the official Instagram Website. And a Google Search gives me multiple SO QA which says the same.

But at the same time, there seems to be a ton of websites, applications, and services and other non-emulators who let you post to Instagram (to mention a few: http://techwiser.com/effectivly-use-instagram-on-pc-upload-pics-bluestacks/ and http://dskgrm.com/ is another one, there also seems to be some WordPress plugins who does it ex. https://github.com/roladn/wordpress-to-instagram but I'm not too good with eirhet PHP or WordPress to be able to tell how they have done it.).

And before anyone reports it as a duplicate. I do not consider this a duplicate since all other QA simply states that it is not possible via the API, but obviously, it is possible somehow, and I'm wondering how.

So I simply wondering how people are successfully implementing this feature when either the API or the official website allows it?

Comment: Well, there's no official way to upload to Instagram. There's the reversed engineer Instagram API that people use, but then, you're screwed if Instagram suddenly changes their APIs.

Comment: Do you have link to it? I have only been able to find an old one who no longer seems to be working...

Comment: Or i there no public one?

Comment: There's that one you linked above that seems to be using this one https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API. I'm sorry, but it's PHP (exactly the same code, but this one is more updated). The `uploadPhotoData` function is in `src/http/HttpInterface.php`. You'll have to dig into it.

Comment: Will take a look thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

No official way to post media to Instagram doesn't mean that there is no way to do this.

If you are a developer you could simply reverse engineering the Instagram API and build some software to use that, otherwise you could just use some tools already developed.

**PHP**
[mgp25/Instagram-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Instagram-API)

**Python**
[b3nab/instapy-cli](https://github.com/b3nab/instapy-cli)

And if this don't fit your needs you can go to github and search some other softwares already developed.